# How to filter rows where label is not present

Tags: pandas

How can I filter for all rows where a label is not present. e.g. I can select rows where the index is 'label', `df.loc['label']`, how can I get the inverse? All rows where the label is not present instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
df[df.index != "label"]
```